# Convert string to time with python

Tags: python, datetime, strftime, strptime

I have read a few stackoverflow posts but still can't figure this out...

I want to crawl craigslist post posted within last 48 hours. Posted time is in the following format for craigslist:

2013-03-15, 7:43PM MDT

I have tried

```
string = "2013-03-15, 7:43PM MDT"

time.strptime(string, "%Y-%m-%d, %I:%M%p %Z")
```

But apparent the format doesnt match the string. What should be the format for this time string?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4766400/2086065

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the MDT. Python's %Z doesn't support that (at least it seems so to me). There are probably better solutions, but this one should work:

```
import time
import datetime

#use the UTC which Python understands
a="2013-03-15, 7:43PM MDT".replace("MDT","UTC")
fs="%Y-%m-%d, %I:%M%p %Z"
c=time.strptime(a, fs)

#converting from UTC to MDT (time difference)
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(c)) - datetime.timedelta(hours=6)
print dt
```