# ValueError time data doesn't match the format

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I am trying to match time zones with empty string in strptime function. Howevr, I get the following error.

```
ValueError: time data 'Thu Apr 14 01:46:29 MDT 2016' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S   %Y'
```

This is the code I try.

```
import datetime

d = datetime.datetime.strptime('Thu Apr 14 01:46:29 MDT 2016', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S   %Y')
```

How to map time-zone in python? 
time zone can be MDT, MST,etc.

Comment: No, all text must be matched. Either remove the timezone characters, or match them as literals with `'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S MDT %Y'`

Comment: It should be `%Z` for that, but the parser doesn't seem to recognize anything but UTC. Even EST and CST, the examples in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), produce an error.

Comment: @Martjin as I mentioned in the question, time-zone can be changed and I don't want to remove time-zone.

Comment: @Tigerhawk, I tried empty string but still it produces error.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 sort of a duplicate, but MDT is also not supported http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447706/convert-string-to-time-with-python

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703546/parsing-date-time-string-with-timezone-abbreviated-name-in-python

Comment: @newday, are your input timezones limited to a few that you know of?

Comment: to the moment it is MST and MDT.

Comment: My concern is why two out of the three examples in the official documentation don't work.

Comment: Try this.` x = "Thu Apr 14 01:46:29 MDT 2016"`   `d = datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S {}  %Y'.format(x.split()[-2]))`   Not sure this will solve your problem ;)

Comment: @newday  Is it working for you?

Answer (score 1):

To parse this specific format (similar to rfc 822 used in emails), you could use `email` packages:

```
from email.utils import parsedate_tz, mktime_tz

time_tuple = parsedate_tz('Thu Apr 14 01:46:29 MDT 2016')
posix_time = mktime_tz(time_tuple)
```

Note: MDT is `-6` hours here ([according to the rfc 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822)). In general, timezone [abbreviations may be ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1703546/4279).

On Python 3.3+, you could create a timezone-aware datetime directly:

```
from email.utils import parsedate_to_datetime

dt = parsedate_to_datetime('Thu Apr 14 01:46:29 MDT 2016')
```

Here's [how to parse it on earlier Python versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23117071/4279).