# How to convert a date with timezone to a timestamp?

Tags: python, python-2.7, timestamp, unix-timestamp

How can I convert a date string that looks like

```
2015-12-02 21:31:49 GMT
```

to a timestamp in Python 2?

Comment: Haven't you tried anything at all?

Comment: @Trilarion: This question has "with timezone" part. The answer depends on how the timezone is specified.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks. What about [Python strptime() and timezones?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305413/python-strptime-and-timezones) or [Parsing date/time string with timezone abbreviated name in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703546/parsing-date-time-string-with-timezone-abbreviated-name-in-python)? They seem to indicate that abbreviating the time zone and then wanting to parse that string is not a good idea anyway because the abbreviations are not unique.

Answer (score 2):

Usually one would use [datetime.strptime()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) or [dateutil.parser.parse()](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) but both ways do not work with timezones as abbreviations. They actually do not store the time zone info if an abbreviation is given (see [Python strptime() and timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305413/python-strptime-and-timezones) and [Parsing date/time string with timezone abbreviated name in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703546/parsing-date-time-string-with-timezone-abbreviated-name-in-python)).

The reason is that the abbreviations are not unique (EST is used both in North America and Australia) and therefore parsing a date string with time zone abbreviations is ambigous.

This means you cannot do the conversion reliably.

Additionally `datetime.strptime()` may not recognize some time zone abbreviations like EST. It may recognize them if it is [a local timezone](http://bugs.python.org/issue22377).

However if by chance you anyway only ever have UTC/GMT, then just do

```
from datetime import datetime
date_string = '2015-12-02 21:31:49 GMT'
date = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks, I added the information.

Comment: meta: this is one of the reasons why answering duplicate questions is bad: the knowledge such as whether and when `.strptime()` understands EST is not accumulated in a single place. Unless OP clarifies what kind of timezone abbreviations are expected in OP's application; the answers from a duplicate question should be used.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
import time
import datetime

ts = time.time()
timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: It converts a timestamp to a time string. OP asks the opposite.