# Parse timezone from a human time input

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I'm having trouble parsing out timezone information from a string that looks like:

`8pm PST on sunday`

So far, using `parsedatetime` and `dateutils` allows me to parse the date out but the timezone usually causes issues.

Anyone know of a library that handles this sort of thing? My fallback is to naively parse out the timezones via a regex or a simple `"PST" in datestring`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The abbreviations you're using [are not unique](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/); you will therefore need to interpret the time zones somehow (e.g. assume United States) and specify what each abbreviation means for your application:

```
from dateutil import parser

# map time zones to seconds from GMT
zones = {
    'EST': -5 * 3600,
    'PST': -8 * 3600
}

parser.parse('8 PM on Sunday PST', tzinfos=zones)
# datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 24, 20, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset('PST', -28800))
```

You can install `dateutil` with `pip`: `pip install python-dateutil`.

See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703546/parsing-date-time-string-with-timezone-abbreviated-name-in-python) for more information.

Comment: Thank you! Let me give this a go