# ValueError time data 'Fri Mar 11 15:59:57 EST 2016' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I am trying to simply create a datetime object from the following date: 'Fri Mar 11 15:59:57 EST 2016' using the format: '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'.

Here's the code.

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.strptime('Fri Mar 11 15:59:57 EST 2016', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
```

However, this results in a ValueError as shown below.

```
ValueError: time data 'Fri Mar 11 15:59:57 EST 2016' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
```

Maybe I am missing something obviously wrong with my format string, but I have checked it over and over. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Edit to reflect comments/questions for more information:

The Python version I'm using is 2.7.6.

Using the 'locale' command on Ubuntu 14.04 I get this:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me; what version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.6

Comment: Are you by any chance using a computer which uses a non-English locale setting?

Comment: Here's the output of the 'locale' command. This is on ubuntu 14.04 on Amazon AWS by the way.  
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: In short, to answer your question, no. It appears the locales are all set to en_US

Comment: Don't know how if your AWS instance is really precious, but you could try `sudo timedatectl set-timezone EST`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the %Z specifier, `strptime` only recognises "UTC", "GMT" and whatever is in `time.tzname` (so whether it recognises "EST" will depend on the time zone of your computer). This is [issue 22377](http://bugs.python.org/issue22377).

See:

- [Python strptime() and timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305413/python-strptime-and-timezones)
- [Parsing date/time string with timezone abbreviated name in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703546/parsing-date-time-string-with-timezone-abbreviated-name-in-python)

The best option for parsing timezones that include a human-readable time zone is still to use the third-party [python-dateutil](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) library:

```
import dateutil
date = dateutil.parse('Fri Mar 11 15:59:57 EST 2016')
```

If you cannot install python-dateutil, you could strip out the timezone and parse it manually e.g. using a dictionary lookup.

Comment: The problem also happens here. Indeed, I figured that the problem was the `EST` substring and you just confirmed the problem. In this case, is there any safe way to parse these strings and avoid this issue?

Comment: @JeandersonBarrosCândido the best option is to use python-dateutil. I've updated my answer to add that, thanks.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is still the best way to handle time zones that `datetime` cannot.