# how to convert a string datetime with unknown timezone to timestamp in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a datetime like this `Thu Jun 02 11:56:53 CDT 2011`
I tried to convert it to datetime object using the code below

```
from dateutil import parser
timestamp = parser.parse("Thu Jun 02 11:56:53 CDT 2011")
```

But I get this warning

```
UnknownTimezoneWarning: tzname CDT identified but not understood. 
Pass `tzinfos` argument in order to correctly return a timezone-aware datetime.
In a future version, this raise an exception.
category=UnknownTimezoneWarning)
```

There is no warning when I use `UTC` instead of `CDT`. 
Can I use `tzinfos` to fix this ?

Comment: "CDT" is an extremely ambiguous identifier. Do you *know* what timezone it should represent?

Comment: CDT is for Central Daylight Time and equals UTC-5, you can replace CDT with UTC-5 and it works

Comment: There's the dateparser package. See this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62714463) contribution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer, without using tzinfos, replace CDT with its UTC equivalent:

```
In [15]: from dateutil import parser
    ...: timestamp = parser.parse("Thu Jun 02 11:56:53 UTC-5 2011")
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [16]: timestamp
Out[16]: datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 2, 11, 56, 53, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 18000))
```

You can use tzinfos, it must be a dict where keys are the unknows timezones and values are either string UTC format (UTC-5 for example) or number of seconds to offset, here is the doc:

> **TZINFOS**
>
> Additional time zone names / aliases which may be present in the
>   string. This argument maps time zone names (and optionally offsets
>   from those time zones) to time zones. This parameter can be a
>   dictionary with timezone aliases mapping time zone names to time zones
>   or a function taking two parameters (tzname and tzoffset) and
>   returning a time zone. The timezones to which the names are mapped can
>   be an integer offset from UTC in seconds or a tzinfo object. This
>   parameter is ignored if ignoretz is set.

I tried with both methods and compared

```
timestamp = parser.parse("Thu Jun 02 11:56:53 CDT 2011", tzinfos={"CDT": -5*3600})
timestamp2 = parser.parse("Thu Jun 02 11:56:53 CDT 2011", tzinfos={"CDT": "UTC-5"})
timestamp3 = parser.parse("Thu Jun 02 11:56:53 UTC-0500 2011")
```

and it prints

```
2011-06-02 11:56:53-05:00
2011-06-02 11:56:53-05:00
2011-06-02 11:56:53+05:00
```

it seems like you have to inverse the sign when using tzinfos (correct me, it might be the inverse thing to do)

Answer (score 17):

collect a timezone info from https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/
as @pLOPeGG answer, you can use as demo

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding:utf-8

from dateutil import parser

whois_timezone_info = {
        "A": 1 * 3600,
        "ACDT": 10.5 * 3600,
        "ACST": 9.5 * 3600,
        "ACT": -5 * 3600,
        "ACWST": 8.75 * 3600,
        "ADT": 4 * 3600,
        "AEDT": 11 * 3600,
        "AEST": 10 * 3600,
        "AET": 10 * 3600,
        "AFT": 4.5 * 3600,
        "AKDT": -8 * 3600,
        "AKST": -9 * 3600,
        "ALMT": 6 * 3600,
        "AMST": -3 * 3600,
        "AMT": -4 * 3600,
        "ANAST": 12 * 3600,
        "ANAT": 12 * 3600,
        "AQTT": 5 * 3600,
        "ART": -3 * 3600,
        "AST": 3 * 3600,
        "AT": -4 * 3600,
        "AWDT": 9 * 3600,
        "AWST": 8 * 3600,
        "AZOST": 0 * 3600,
        "AZOT": -1 * 3600,
        "AZST": 5 * 3600,
        "AZT": 4 * 3600,
        "AoE": -12 * 3600,
        "B": 2 * 3600,
        "BNT": 8 * 3600,
        "BOT": -4 * 3600,
        "BRST": -2 * 3600,
        "BRT": -3 * 3600,
        "BST": 6 * 3600,
        "BTT": 6 * 3600,
        "C": 3 * 3600,
        "CAST": 8 * 3600,
        "CAT": 2 * 3600,
        "CCT": 6.5 * 3600,
        "CDT": -5 * 3600,
        "CEST": 2 * 3600,
        "CET": 1 * 3600,
        "CHADT": 13.75 * 3600,
        "CHAST": 12.75 * 3600,
        "CHOST": 9 * 3600,
        "CHOT": 8 * 3600,
        "CHUT": 10 * 3600,
        "CIDST": -4 * 3600,
        "CIST": -5 * 3600,
        "CKT": -10 * 3600,
        "CLST": -3 * 3600,
        "CLT": -4 * 3600,
        "COT": -5 * 3600,
        "CST": -6 * 3600,
        "CT": -6 * 3600,
        "CVT": -1 * 3600,
        "CXT": 7 * 3600,
        "ChST": 10 * 3600,
        "D": 4 * 3600,
        "DAVT": 7 * 3600,
        "DDUT": 10 * 3600,
        "E": 5 * 3600,
        "EASST": -5 * 3600,
        "EAST": -6 * 3600,
        "EAT": 3 * 3600,
        "ECT": -5 * 3600,
        "EDT": -4 * 3600,
        "EEST": 3 * 3600,
        "EET": 2 * 3600,
        "EGST": 0 * 3600,
        "EGT": -1 * 3600,
        "EST": -5 * 3600,
        "ET": -5 * 3600,
        "F": 6 * 3600,
        "FET": 3 * 3600,
        "FJST": 13 * 3600,
        "FJT": 12 * 3600,
        "FKST": -3 * 3600,
        "FKT": -4 * 3600,
        "FNT": -2 * 3600,
        "G": 7 * 3600,
        "GALT": -6 * 3600,
        "GAMT": -9 * 3600,
        "GET": 4 * 3600,
        "GFT": -3 * 3600,
        "GILT": 12 * 3600,
        "GMT": 0 * 3600,
        "GST": 4 * 3600,
        "GYT": -4 * 3600,
        "H": 8 * 3600,
        "HDT": -9 * 3600,
        "HKT": 8 * 3600,
        "HOVST": 8 * 3600,
        "HOVT": 7 * 3600,
        "HST": -10 * 3600,
        "I": 9 * 3600,
        "ICT": 7 * 3600,
        "IDT": 3 * 3600,
        "IOT": 6 * 3600,
        "IRDT": 4.5 * 3600,
        "IRKST": 9 * 3600,
        "IRKT": 8 * 3600,
        "IRST": 3.5 * 3600,
        "IST": 5.5 * 3600,
        "JST": 9 * 3600,
        "K": 10 * 3600,
        "KGT": 6 * 3600,
        "KOST": 11 * 3600,
        "KRAST": 8 * 3600,
        "KRAT": 7 * 3600,
        "KST": 9 * 3600,
        "KUYT": 4 * 3600,
        "L": 11 * 3600,
        "LHDT": 11 * 3600,
        "LHST": 10.5 * 3600,
        "LINT": 14 * 3600,
        "M": 12 * 3600,
        "MAGST": 12 * 3600,
        "MAGT": 11 * 3600,
        "MART": 9.5 * 3600,
        "MAWT": 5 * 3600,
        "MDT": -6 * 3600,
        "MHT": 12 * 3600,
        "MMT": 6.5 * 3600,
        "MSD": 4 * 3600,
        "MSK": 3 * 3600,
        "MST": -7 * 3600,
        "MT": -7 * 3600,
        "MUT": 4 * 3600,
        "MVT": 5 * 3600,
        "MYT": 8 * 3600,
        "N": -1 * 3600,
        "NCT": 11 * 3600,
        "NDT": 2.5 * 3600,
        "NFT": 11 * 3600,
        "NOVST": 7 * 3600,
        "NOVT": 7 * 3600,
        "NPT": 5.5 * 3600,
        "NRT": 12 * 3600,
        "NST": 3.5 * 3600,
        "NUT": -11 * 3600,
        "NZDT": 13 * 3600,
        "NZST": 12 * 3600,
        "O": -2 * 3600,
        "OMSST": 7 * 3600,
        "OMST": 6 * 3600,
        "ORAT": 5 * 3600,
        "P": -3 * 3600,
        "PDT": -7 * 3600,
        "PET": -5 * 3600,
        "PETST": 12 * 3600,
        "PETT": 12 * 3600,
        "PGT": 10 * 3600,
        "PHOT": 13 * 3600,
        "PHT": 8 * 3600,
        "PKT": 5 * 3600,
        "PMDT": -2 * 3600,
        "PMST": -3 * 3600,
        "PONT": 11 * 3600,
        "PST": -8 * 3600,
        "PT": -8 * 3600,
        "PWT": 9 * 3600,
        "PYST": -3 * 3600,
        "PYT": -4 * 3600,
        "Q": -4 * 3600,
        "QYZT": 6 * 3600,
        "R": -5 * 3600,
        "RET": 4 * 3600,
        "ROTT": -3 * 3600,
        "S": -6 * 3600,
        "SAKT": 11 * 3600,
        "SAMT": 4 * 3600,
        "SAST": 2 * 3600,
        "SBT": 11 * 3600,
        "SCT": 4 * 3600,
        "SGT": 8 * 3600,
        "SRET": 11 * 3600,
        "SRT": -3 * 3600,
        "SST": -11 * 3600,
        "SYOT": 3 * 3600,
        "T": -7 * 3600,
        "TAHT": -10 * 3600,
        "TFT": 5 * 3600,
        "TJT": 5 * 3600,
        "TKT": 13 * 3600,
        "TLT": 9 * 3600,
        "TMT": 5 * 3600,
        "TOST": 14 * 3600,
        "TOT": 13 * 3600,
        "TRT": 3 * 3600,
        "TVT": 12 * 3600,
        "U": -8 * 3600,
        "ULAST": 9 * 3600,
        "ULAT": 8 * 3600,
        "UTC": 0 * 3600,
        "UYST": -2 * 3600,
        "UYT": -3 * 3600,
        "UZT": 5 * 3600,
        "V": -9 * 3600,
        "VET": -4 * 3600,
        "VLAST": 11 * 3600,
        "VLAT": 10 * 3600,
        "VOST": 6 * 3600,
        "VUT": 11 * 3600,
        "W": -10 * 3600,
        "WAKT": 12 * 3600,
        "WARST": -3 * 3600,
        "WAST": 2 * 3600,
        "WAT": 1 * 3600,
        "WEST": 1 * 3600,
        "WET": 0 * 3600,
        "WFT": 12 * 3600,
        "WGST": -2 * 3600,
        "WGT": -3 * 3600,
        "WIB": 7 * 3600,
        "WIT": 9 * 3600,
        "WITA": 8 * 3600,
        "WST": 14 * 3600,
        "WT": 0 * 3600,
        "X": -11 * 3600,
        "Y": -12 * 3600,
        "YAKST": 10 * 3600,
        "YAKT": 9 * 3600,
        "YAPT": 10 * 3600,
        "YEKST": 6 * 3600,
        "YEKT": 5 * 3600,
        "Z": 0 * 3600,
}

timestamp = parser.parse("Thu Jun 02 11:56:53 CDT 2011", tzinfos={"CDT": -5*3600})
```

Comment: i made a mistakes, it should like [gist - timezone parser](https://gist.github.com/h-j-13/e3a585796510b59601e34a07e99b386d)

Comment: you can edit your post rather than giving the link to the correct format.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. `dateutil` produces the following error for some timezones: `Offset must be tzinfo subclass, tz string or int offset`. All because some numbers (e.g. `"CHADT": 13.75 * 3600`) are not integers.

Comment: @Vasniktel, actually there are non-integer timezone offsets, for instance, half an hour.

Comment: @Vasniktel will typecasting the value to `int` be considered fine? Will it cause any rounding errors?

Comment: @Ja8zyjits Typecasting worked fine in my case. All numbers nicely multiply by 3600 and lose the fraction.

Comment: @MaurícioCollaça You are totally right. The issue, tho, is that multiplying a float by 3600 yields a float and that is what `dateutil` complains about. Typecasting it to int works well for me.