# Error: UnknownTimezoneWarning: tzname IST identified but not understood

Tags: python, datefinder

```
Error :  UnknownTimezoneWarning: tzname IST identified but not understood.  Pass `tzinfos` argument in order to correctly return a timezone-aware datetime.  In a future version, this will raise an exception.
  category=UnknownTimezoneWarning)
```

I'm using [datefinder](https://datefinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for getting the date out of a string.

This is a sample code:

```
import datefinder

a =  'Last Updated :16th July 2020 18:00 IST'
matches = list(datefinder.find_dates(a, source = True ))
print (matches)
```

Output :

```
UnknownTimezoneWarning: tzname IST identified but not understood.  Pass `tzinfos` argument in order to correctly return a timezone-aware datetime.  In a future version, this will raise an exception.
  category=UnknownTimezoneWarning)
[(datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 16, 18, 0), '16th July 2020 18:00 IST')]
```

How can I eliminate the above error? (It works fine while using UTC in the string 'a' in place of IST(Indian Standard Time))

Comment: Take a look at the following at the following link where they discuss how to address the above error you are having https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206500/how-to-convert-a-string-datetime-with-unknown-timezone-to-timestamp-in-python

Comment: Yeah I've read this article. But I'm using `datefinder` not `dateutil`. How to deal with this error in datefinder?

Comment: datefinder is using the dateutil library internally

Comment: If you change  a =  'Last Updated :16th July 2020 18:00 IST' , the string to this: a =  'Last Updated :16th July 2020 18:00 UTC-5.5'  . it should hopefullt work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to convert a string datetime with unknown timezone to timestamp in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206500/how-to-convert-a-string-datetime-with-unknown-timezone-to-timestamp-in-python)