# Converting PDT/PST timezone column to UTC timezone

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, jupyter-notebook

I have a pandas column that has both PDT and PST datetime values.
Example:

| PDT/PST |
| --- |
| 2021-10-29 00:18:38 PDT |
| 2021-10-29 01:08:19 PDT |
| 2021-11-08 19:43:58 PST |
| 2021-11-08 19:56:01 PST |

I need to convert these into UTC time zone.
Example:

| UTC |
| --- |
| 2021-10-29 07:18:00 |

A simple answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with convert strings to datetimes by [`dateparser.parse`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4766400/2901002):

```
import dateparser

df['PDT/PST'] = pd.to_datetime(df['PDT/PST'].apply(dateparser.parse), utc=True)
print (df)
                    PDT/PST
0 2021-10-29 07:18:38+00:00
1 2021-10-29 08:08:19+00:00
2 2021-11-09 03:43:58+00:00
3 2021-11-09 03:56:01+00:00
```

Last add [`Series.dt.tz_localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize.html) with `None`:

```
df['PDT/PST'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['PDT/PST'].apply(dateparser.parse), utc=True)
                   .dt.tz_localize(None))
print (df)
              PDT/PST
0 2021-10-29 07:18:38
1 2021-10-29 08:08:19
2 2021-11-09 03:43:58
3 2021-11-09 03:56:01
```

Solution with replace `PST` and `PDT` to `-7` or `-8` is:

```
df['PDT/PST'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['PDT/PST']
                                .replace({'PDT':'-07:00','PST':'-08:00'}, regex=True), utc=True)
                  .dt.tz_localize(None))
print (df)
              PDT/PST
0 2021-10-29 07:18:38
1 2021-10-29 08:08:19
2 2021-11-09 03:43:58
3 2021-11-09 03:56:01
```

Comment: Your output is not in UTC.

Comment: @SalvinD'souza - Can you test alternative solution?

Comment: interestingly, dateparser parses to Python datetime object with fixed UTC offset - I wasn't aware of this (since mixed offsets here, pandas keeps the dtype). In the sense of "correct behavior", I think dateutil's parser does a better job since it at least issues a warning if you feed it with abbreviated tz names (since might be ambiguous).

Comment: @jezrael  This solution (pd.to_datetime(df['PDT/PST']
                                .replace({'PDT':'-07:00','PST':'-08:00'}, regex=True), utc=True)
                  .dt.tz_localize(None)) worked flawlessly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Another option: dateutil's parser with tzinfos supplied; then convert to UTC.

```
import dateutil
pacific_tz = dateutil.tz.gettz("US/Pacific")

df['UTC'] = df['PDT/PST'].apply(dateutil.parser.parse,
                                tzinfos={'PST': pacific_tz,
                                         'PDT': pacific_tz}).dt.tz_convert('UTC')

df['UTC']

0   2021-10-29 07:18:38+00:00
1   2021-10-29 08:08:19+00:00
2   2021-11-09 03:43:58+00:00
3   2021-11-09 03:56:01+00:00
Name: UTC, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

Related: [Python strptime() and timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3305413/10197418)

Now you could format to string with a certain format if desired, e.g.

```
df['UTC'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

0    2021-10-29 07:18:38
1    2021-10-29 08:08:19
2    2021-11-09 03:43:58
3    2021-11-09 03:56:01
Name: UTC, dtype: object
```

Comment: If performance is important, second solution with replace by `{'PDT':'-07:00','PST':'-08:00'}` is not better? I ask, because you are expert for datetimes (in my opinion ;) )

Comment: @jezrael yes I think that would be more efficient performance-wise. You just have to know the correct UTC offsets ^^