# How can I convert the time stamp with timezone info to utc time in python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I have the time string like this "2023-09-06T22:02:44-07:00", which is obtained through calling

```
datetime.now().astimezone().isoformat(timespec='seconds')
```

My question is how to convert the time string "2023-09-06T22:02:44-07:00" to utc time? Basically how to convert it so that -07:00 will be +00:00?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first use the `fromisoformat` method to convert the timestamp string to a `datetime` object, then call the `astimezone(timezone.utc)` method to convert it to UTC timezone, and output the converted timestamp in ISO format with `isoformat`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

t = "2023-09-06T22:02:44-07:00"
print(datetime.fromisoformat(t).astimezone(timezone.utc).isoformat(timespec='seconds'))
```

This outputs:

```
2023-09-07T05:02:44+00:00
```

Comment: a followup question, if I want to get the time string like "2023-09-06T22:02:44-PDT" (instead of 07:00 in the end) and also convert it to UTC, is there any quick way to do that?

Comment: Oops I think I misunderstood your follow-up quesiton. If you actually mean to convert `"2023-09-06T22:02:44-PDT"` to a UTC timestamp you can try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62714463/6890912