# How to convert the hour difference in timezone info to the abbreviated timezone name

Tags: python, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

This is a followup question to

[How can I convert the time stamp with timezone info to utc time in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77056774/how-can-i-convert-the-time-stamp-with-timezone-info-to-utc-time-in-python/77056831#77056831)

I was able to get the time string like this "2023-09-06T22:02:44-07:00" through calling

```
datetime.now().astimezone().isoformat(timespec='seconds')
```

I wonder whether there is a way to get the time string like "2023-09-06T22:02:44-PDT"? And also convert the time string to UTC time -- something like "2023-09-07T05:02:44-UTC"? Thanks!

Comment: There are many timezones that are UTC-07:00 (including in Canada and Mexico for example). How are you expecting Python to identify it as "PDT" and not one of the others?

Comment: No, there is not. Given the [rules of a time zone](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), the mapping of time zone --> UTC offset (such as -07:00) is unambiguous. This is not true in the other direction ! The only way you can map -07:00 to "PDT" (which isn't a time zone either, btw.) is by *defining it by yourself, i.e. '-07:00 should always map to "PDT"'.

Answer (score 0):

Get the timezone-naive timestamp and append the timezone-aware `tzname` to get your desired format

```
now = datetime.now()
print(now.isoformat(timespec="seconds") + "-" + now.astimezone().tzname())
```

or use `strftime` with `%Z`

```
datetime.now().astimezone().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-%Z")
```